# Choose stdout or stderr based on function argument

Tags: c++, templates, iostream

I want to create a template that prints any container which its element can be printed by std::cout or any other stream.

I want to be able to tell which stream it should print into, therefore somehow I need to pass the target stream as an arguemnt? Below is the code that I came up with. But there are couple of problems that I havent figured out yet

If I use `fprintf()` then I can directly pass the `stream` as argument to `fprintf` but then the problem is the element need to be a `char *` while std::cout will take care of type conversion I suppose much easier?

```
template<template<typename...> typename C, typename E, typename S>
void my_printer(const C<E>& container,
                     S separator = ' ',
                     FILE *stream = stdout) {

  typename C<E>::size_type index = 0;
  typename C<E>::size_type lastIndex = container.size() - 1;

  for (const auto& element: container) {
    if (stream == stdout) {
      std::cout << element;
      if (index < lastIndex) {
        std::cout << separator;
      }
    } else if (stream == stderr) {
      std::cerr << element;
      if (index < lastIndex) {
        std::cerr << separator;
      }
    }
    index++;
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Notes: If you need the index, just you a plain old `for` loop. Save yourself some duplication of code and effort: Determine the stream you want up at the top once, take a reference to the stream, and use the reference inside the loop. What will you do when someone hands you a `stream` that represents a file or a socket?

Comment: The question makes no reference to the Standard Template Library or ranges, so I removed those tags.

Comment: Why are you passing in `stdout`/`stderr` instead of `std::cout` and `std::cerr` directly?

Comment: And as soon as you pass one of the standard streams, the whole question goes away.

Comment: [Simplified](https://godbolt.org/z/Yq9oYvKGY)

Comment: @user4581301 with an indexed loop it does not work if the container is list, then I can not use `container[i]`

Comment: Good point. Wouldn't work with a `set` or `map` either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the parameter to a `std::ostream &`:

```
template<template<typename...> typename C, typename E, typename S>
void my_printer(const C<E>& container,
                     S separator = ' ',
                     std::ostream &stream=std::cout) {
```

Now, you can pass either `std::cerr` or, explicitly, `std::cout` if you feel like it, and then use all the regular stream formatted operations.

Answer (score 1):

C++23 supports `std::print` that can write to `FILE`:

```cpp
template <typename Container>
void my_printer(const Container& container,
                char separator = ' ',
                FILE *stream = stdout) {
  typename Container::size_type index = 0;
  typename Container::size_type lastIndex = container.size() - 1;

  for (const auto& element: container) {
    std::print(stream, "{}", element);
    if (index < lastIndex) {
      std::print(stream, "{}", separator);
    }
    index++;
  }
}
```

Here is an example using the {fmt} library, `std::print` is based on: https://godbolt.org/z/M684WMfP6.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of {fmt} and C++23 `std::print`